# TFLite model error, Regular TensorFlow ops are not supported by this interpreter

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I have installed `tflite_runtime 2.5.0.post1` using `!pip install --extra-index-url https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/ tflite_runtime` command on `Windows 11` and tried to do inference with my Image Captioning model.

Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import tflite_runtime.interpreter as tflite

max_len = 20
word_to_idx = np.load('weights/word_to_idx.npy', allow_pickle = True).item()
idx_to_word = np.load('weights/idx_to_word.npy', allow_pickle = True).item()

FEATURE_GENERATION_MODEL_TFLITE = 'feature_generation_model.tflite'
CAPTION_GENERATION_MODEL_TFLITE = 'caption_generation_model.tflite'

def predict_caption(path):
    a = Image.open(path)
    a = a.resize((300, 300))
    a = np.asarray(a, dtype = 'float32')
    imgp = a.reshape(1, 300, 300, 3)
    
    # Model 1
    # feature extraction model
    feat_interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path = FEATURE_GENERATION_MODEL_TFLITE)
    feat_interpreter.allocate_tensors()

    input_index = feat_interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['index']
    output_index = feat_interpreter.get_output_details()[0]['index']

    feat_interpreter.set_tensor(input_index, imgp)
    feat_interpreter.invoke()
    
    feature_vector = feat_interpreter.get_tensor(output_index)
    feature_vector = feature_vector.reshape((1, 1536))
    
    # We got feature vector using the feature extration tflite model
    # Now generating caption using these features
    
    in_text = 'startseq'
    
    for i in range(max_len):
        seq = [word_to_idx[w] for w in in_text.split() if w in word_to_idx]
        seq = pad_sequences([seq], maxlen = max_len, padding = 'post')
        
        # Model 2
        # Caption Generation Model
        cap_interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path = CAPTION_GENERATION_MODEL_TFLITE)
        cap_interpreter.allocate_tensors()

        input_index1 = cap_interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['index']
        input_index2 = cap_interpreter.get_input_details()[1]['index']
        output_index = cap_interpreter.get_output_details()[0]['index']
        
        cap_interpreter.set_tensor(input_index1, feature_vector)
        cap_interpreter.set_tensor(input_index2, np.float32(seq))
        cap_interpreter.invoke()
        
        y_pred = cap_interpreter.get_tensor(output_index)
        y_pred = y_pred.argmax()
        
        word = idx_to_word[y_pred]
        in_text += ' '+word
        
        if word == 'endseq':
            break

    final_caption = in_text.split()[1:-1]
    final_caption = ' '.join(final_caption)

    return final_caption
```

But when I am calling `predict_caption('images/image.jpg')` function it is giving me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10744\846162487.py in <module>
----> 1 predict_caption('images/image.jpg')

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10744\3775461012.py in predict_caption(path)
     91         cap_interpreter.set_tensor(input_index1, feature_vector)
     92         cap_interpreter.set_tensor(input_index2, np.float32(seq))
---> 93         cap_interpreter.invoke()
     94 
     95         y_pred = cap_interpreter.get_tensor(output_index)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflite_runtime\interpreter.py in invoke(self)
    831     """
    832     self._ensure_safe()
--> 833     self._interpreter.Invoke()
    834 
    835   def reset_all_variables(self):

RuntimeError: Regular TensorFlow ops are not supported by this interpreter. Make sure you apply/link the Flex delegate before inference.Node number 9 (FlexTensorListReserve) failed to prepare.
```

I have no idea why this is happening, can anyone help here?
When I use `import tensorflow.lite as tflite` this code is working fine, but I don't want to use tensorflow. I want to use `tflite_runtime`.

This is how I converted my tensorflow model into tflite models:

```
# Feature Model

FEATURE_GENERATION_MODEL_TFLITE = 'feature_generation_model.tflite'

tf_lite_converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(feature_generation_model)
feature_tflite_model = tf_lite_converter.convert()
open(FEATURE_GENERATION_MODEL_TFLITE, 'wb').write(feature_tflite_model)

# Captioning Model

CAPTION_GENERATION_MODEL_TFLITE = 'caption_generation_model.tflite'

tf_lite_converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(image_captioning_model)

tf_lite_converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tf_lite_converter.experimental_new_converter = True
tf_lite_converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]

caption_tflite_model = tf_lite_converter.convert()
open(CAPTION_GENERATION_MODEL_TFLITE, 'wb').write(caption_tflite_model)
```

If anyone wants to reproduce this code, [here is a link to Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BmrIwpabyTp3WAtcVpkQX1uN5dXhAI0R?usp=sharing), it has code, model weights, and tflite model.